# How to set environment variables in Linux which takes effect immediately and for everything?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I want a way to set environment variables in Linux which takes effect immediately and on everything.

For example, I set up proxy:

```
export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:42949
```

That takes effect immediately. But it only works in one terminal and for one user (puzzling; some apps like firefox use it. But when I run `env` as another user, I couldn't see `$http_proxy`). If I set proxy through adding script to `/etc/profile.d/`, that works for everything, but won't take effect until anyone sources it.

Comment: You can't set an environment variable for a running application belonging to another user. You also can't change the environment of a running application that you own, from a shell.  It appears that this question is partly about the way environment variables propagate between processes and their child processes.

Comment: You'll need a workaround. What is might be, depends on what you're doing exactly. You might be able to use files.

Comment: To give some rationale to the "you can't do that" answers: it's a security measure. Imagine you have a bad actor on your system. Image the damage he could cause by setting environment variables that affect every process running on your machine.

Answer (score 4):

> I want a way to set environment variables in Linux which takes effect immediately and on everything.

You can't do that.

Environment variables can be propagated downwards from a process to its children *as those children are created*. You cannot share an environment variable upwards from child to parent, nor can you share it sideways to other processes - even those that you own.

As suggested [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699573/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux-which-takes-effect-immediately-and-for#comment1322464_699573), there might be other solutions to the underlying problem, but you'll have to [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/699573/edit) to explain what it is you're trying to achieve.